# Not possible to run Android Studio and Docker on Windows because of Hyper V

Tags: android, windows, docker, hyper-v

So, I am having an issue with running both, Android Studio and Docker, because Docker needs Hyper V and Android Studio won't launch a virtual device when Hyper V is active.
Has anyone else experienced this?

[image: This is my Android Studio error, when Hyper V is activated]

EDIT:
Virtualization is activated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem for computers without an "Intel" processor. Install any emulator with Genymotion (VirtualBox optional) because currently the new versions of docker no longer require VirtualBox.

Although if you are very lucky and / or have a computer with an intel processor, simply activate virtualization from BIOS.

Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOuTxfzCvMY

Comment: I do have an intel processor.i5 8600. And a Gigabyte B360M-DS3H. I dont seem to find the correct location in BIOS to activate..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDeje9wgDp4 see this tutorial.

Comment: http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b360m-ds3h_1001_e.pdf

As per this manual, the only setting is vt-d, which is enabled and not enough as you need vt-x. This sucks really bad. My intel shouldn't be the problem, but this mainboard.

Comment: As you see in my edit, virtualization seems to be activated.

Comment: I just realized, you ment to install an Android Emulator other than the Android Studio AVD. So yours is the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: hey i am facing the same solution , how u solved this issue?